# Text in Chrome showing up as gibberish on my website

Tags: html, text, unicode

My portfolio site's text is working fine in Safari but showing as gibberish in Chrome. I've saved as UTF-8 and have meta charset="UTF-8" in my header. Site is [www.jwaltersdesign.com](http://www.jwaltersdesign.com). Any tips will be appreciated.I'm using Version 102.0.5005.61 on Mac

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. I'm using Windows 10 64 bit. English. Please add what you are using to your question.

Comment: Works fine for me as well, Chrome Version 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm using Version 102.0.5005.61 on Mac

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you include a small screenshot of what you termed gibberish?